# Why is a non-accepted answer having way more upvotes than the accepted one is listed last?

Tags: support, answers, up-votes, sorting

I just came across a question on Stack Overflow where the best answer (by consensus, not the accepted one) is at the very bottom of the list of answers, while it has 3 times more upvotes than the accepted one.

It was the first posted answer. It is the shortest answer. Most upvotes. Being last, feels like a bit broken...

**The question in question:** [How can I check if a javascript variable is function type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-variable-is-function-type)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That answer is only sorted last if you picked the *activity* sorting option on the page.

It is sorted **second** (after the accepted answer) if you use the *votes* sorting order instead:

[image: votes sort order]

It would also be sorted second if you picked *oldest*.

The answer sort order is stored as a preference with your profile, so if you picked a different sort order before and forgot you did so, this may catch you by surprise from time to time.

Comment: Nice catch. Hmmm. So what happened, is that SO remembered that sometime in the past I ordered by active. I just arrived from a google search, and had the list presented that way. Wondering if forcing ordering to be based on votes, could be a better option, but this feels to be more complex than to be simply discussed in a few comments...

Comment: Yes, the sort order is a preference stored with your profile. I'm sure someone has already proposed a feature-request to force the sort to always default to votes.